# Getting Checkbox value in php when page loads/opens

Tags: php

How with the help of PHP to diplsy/show the value/values of the selected (checked) checkboxes.

```
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="categoryBox[]" checked onclick="clickOnCategoryBox($(this));">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="categoryBox[]" onclick="clickOnCategoryBox($(this));">
```

The page already loads with one or more checkboxes selected. So I only need to **echo the values** of the selected checkboxes. I know how to make it with JQuery. However I wander if it is possible with PHP.

*PS: the page already loads with the checked checkbox*.

Comment: PHP is a *server* language.  It only runs on the server.  Once it gets sent to the client PHP has nothing to do with it.  Since the page is loading with some of the checkboxes checked you are obviously setting them to something.  
You should therefore know what they are set to wherever you are setting them.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is sending the HTML to the client.

The checkbox is checked because the HTML says it should be checked via the `checked` attribute.

Build the logic for PHP to echo the values into the code which determines if the `checked` attribute should be set or not.